# Strange Lines with Kinect/Asus Xtion in depth frame

Tags: kinect, openni

I'm using OpenNI but I get a minor problem with the depth frame I acquired from the sensors. I have 9 Kinect For Windows, 1 Kinect for Xbox 360 and 3 Asus Xtion and every single one of them shows strange lines that segments the frame and they change position over time. I still can do whatever algorithm I want with these frames, but it bothers me that the lines actually show.

Here's a photo:

[image]